# Add characters from filename to column name

Tags: python, pandas, csv, glob

I have a folder of csv files labelled as such:

`aa_bbb_2009_10.csv`

`aa_bbb_2009_100.csv`

`xx_bbb_2009_10.csv`

`xx_bbb_2009_100.csv`

All with the same column names within. My end goal is to bring all of these into Python and join all the columns together based on the column `ID`, but be able to identify where the column came from based on its name.

I would like the dfs to have column names:

df1:

```
ID   v1_aa_10    v2_aa_10   v3_aa_10
```

df2:

```
ID   v1_aa_100   v2_aa_100  v3_aa_100
```

df3:

```
ID   v1_xx_10   v2_xx_10  v3_xx_10
```

df4:

```
ID   v1_xx_100   v2_xx_100  v3_xx_100
```

To read in all csv files I have:

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

path = ".../folder/"

all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))

for file in all_files:
    file_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))[0]
    dfn = pd.read_csv(file)
    dfn.index.name = file_name
```

Comment: IMO you'd be better off just storing the df as the values in a dictionary with the filename as the key, your proposal requires you to somehow keep track of dfN with whatever file it came from by reading a column name

Comment: Alternatively, just use 3 columns with a combined dataframe and store filename in a separate column. Since you haven't lost data <-> filename mapping, you can extract what you need at any point afterwards.

Comment: it might be worth considering your approach as suggested by others. But if you want to add the characters from file name to column name for each dataframe then you can use the `suffix=` or `prefix=` in `pd.read_csv(..)`

Answer (score 1):

I think need `dictionary of DataFrame` with `key`s of filenames and add `index_col` for `index` from `ID` column if want join by [`concat`](http://pands.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))
dfs = {os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(f))[0]: pd.read_csv(f, index_col=['ID']) for f in files}
df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
```

Or create new column:

```
dfs =[pd.read_csv(f, index_col=['ID']).assign(New=os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(f))[0]) for f in files]
df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
```